# How to set a default value based on the current_user?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to set a default value based on the *User* creating it and I wonder how to do that:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :invoice

  after_initialize :default_values

  ...

  private

  def default_values
    self.tax_rate = current_user.tax_rate || 0
  end

end
```

The problem is that I can't use the current_user inside the model.

This is what I've got in my controller:

```
def create
  @invoice = Invoice.new(params[:invoice])
  3.times { @invoice.items.build }
  ...
end
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass attributes to the `build` method, so you can remove the `after_initialize` ed edit the controller:

```
def create
  @invoice = Invoice.new(params[:invoice])
  3.times { @invoice.items.build( :tax_rate => current_user.tax_rate }
  ...
end
```

Comment: @Tintin81 is set as an accessor to the Invoice so you can set it only once in the controller, you can read it in the Item, and it will not be stored on the database. This will also save you from mass assignment from the web page.

Comment: @Tintin81 I completely rewrote thew answer with a solution which removes all the coupling from the classes.